# TypeError: Property '$'

Tags: jquery, debugging, quicksand

I'm getting an error with my jQuery.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function jquery.custom.js:19


portfolio_quicksand jquery.custom.js:19
(anonymous function) jquery.custom.js:71
l jquery.js:2
c.fireWith jquery.js:2
v.extend.ready jquery.js:2
A jquery.js:2
```

This is the line 19 of the javascript. It looks fine to me. Any thoughts would be great! 
    $filter = $('.filter li.active a').attr('class');

I'm calling jQuery like the following...

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 }
```

Comment: Have you checked if jquery is imported correctly, press ctrl-shift-k and look if your jquery.js or whatever is imported properly.

Comment: Yes, it looks as though its including /jquery.js?ver=1.8.3

Comment: @b-lew don't paste the localhost links

Comment: @Peeyush I just edited that....

Comment: Can you provide scripts in your example?

Comment: @Dom Here is the script... http://pastie.org/6395170 I'm working with Wordpress which is loading jQuery automatically.

Comment: @b-lew Can you just try this  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //your code here
 }

Comment: Are you loading jquery script **BEFORE** this script? If not, it won't know what jQuery or `$` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just try this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //your code here });`

Answer (score 0):

try :

$(document).ready(function(){...})

$ is just a short cut for jQuery(document).ready(function() {}

Are you sure you are using jQuery or Java in your custom script (line 19) ?

Comment: Here is the script that isn't working. getting the error on line 7. http://pastie.org/6395170

Comment: @b-lew where is the script?

Comment: Source code says I'm using /jquery.js?ver=1.8.3 Wordpress loads this by default.

Comment: @Peeyush I've pasted the link above ^

Comment: Awww, it's in word press. Totally different kettle of fish, Have you tried manually installing jQuery to the header.php file ?     
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: @b-lew okay that's good... i just pasted the answer also for you. If it worked for you then please accept is as a solution.

Comment: @b-lew , I know it's just code but word press have a funny way of dealing with jQuery. When I am dealing with themes I usually have to import jQuery in the header.php cause it is never link correctly through the word press method.